# PnP with Modern Auth and App Registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

We are using Modern Auth and when working with PnP you need to setup an App Reg. However as far as I can see its all or nothing? Is there any way to make an App Reg that only have permissions to a set of site collections and not all?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the permissions of the API are all by designed, you could not grant the permission for a set of site collections.

If you want to improve it, you can post the idea in the azure [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).